# How to use 2 different values of 'THIS' in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, this

So I have this function inside a Component:

```
clickedResultHandler = (embedLink) => {
    this.setState({embedSrcLink: embedLink});
}
```

this function is called inside a descendant like this:

```
<div onClick={() => props.clickedResult(embedSrcLink)} className="result">
```

What I want to do is: when I click on this div (with className='result') I want do something with that div. meaning I need to access **this** keyword where this=the div that was clicked. But inside the function definition, I also need to access **this** where this=the Component itself where the function is defined so that I may set the state.

I've looked around and still haven't found a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will get `event.target` like this:

`<div onClick={(event) => props.clickedResult(event, embedSrcLink)} className="result">`

```
clickedResultHandler = (event, embedLink) => {
    console.log(event.target);
    this.setState({embedSrcLink: embedLink});
}
```

The target event property returns the element that triggered the event.

You can also use `event.currentTarget` which always refers to the element whose event listener triggered the event.

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass the `Event` parameter to the clickedResultHandler method.

```
clickedResultHandler = (embedLink) => (e) {
    // e.currentTarget is your div
    this.setState({embedSrcLink: embedLink});
}
```